# How to set color on mouse hover - css

Tags: html, css, image, hover, opacity

I have social bar on my website which indcludes facebook, twitter, google+ and rss.

**It looks like this**

[image]

On mouse hover, i want the circle around image to change color to blue. Somehow i always end up failing and the whole background changes to blue.

**MY HTML CODE**

```
<div class="social-top-nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" title="facebook" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png" title="twitter" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/google.png" title="google+" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/feed.png" title="rss" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**My CSS code**

```
.social-top-nav{
    float:right;
    margin-top: 11px;
}

.social-top-nav ul li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.social-top-nav ul li a{
    display:block;
}

.social-top-nav ul li a img:hover{
    opacity: 0.8;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ccc; 
}
```

**Can you guys help me fix the code? I'll appreciate any input.**

**knitevision**

[image]

Comment: Can you share a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: create a demo of your stuff

Comment: create a demo. this code is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't change the color of the circle (since it's part of the image)

but you can :

1 - add a css border circle (and then change the color):

```
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 50%;
```

2 - try to replace your images with [Font Icons](https://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/)

3 - use [webkit-filter](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/css/filters/index.html) (this won't solve your problem, I'm posting just in case)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this css

```
.social-top-nav:hover {
  color:blue;
 }
```